# Question About the Solutions to the Eight Queens Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

How is $a_{15}n_8e_9k_5f_{10}d_7b_4m_6$ a solution to the Eight Queens problem? [J. W. L. Glaisher, *On the Problem of the Eight Queens*, **Philosophical Magazine**, 1847](http://books.google.com/books?id=nKxSCc5_cCcC&pg=PA457&lpg=PA457&dq=glaisher%20on%20the%20problem%20of%20the%20eight%20queens&source=bl&ots=3FsFz-lPDF&sig=66bdEtWGsZQy3jkzcR3VDgQEOyU&hl=en&ei=8Jl-TuijA4nWiALumYCYCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=glaisher%20on%20the%20problem%20of%20the%20eight%20queens&f=false) says that each one of these terms (letter number combinations) that make up the solution, represent a square on a chessboard. But how do these terms represent a square on a chessboard? A chessboard only has 64 squares/cells, where a, b, c, d, e, f, g, and h are separate columns, consisting of 8 squares/cells each.

Let: a8 = top left corner, h8 = top right corner, a1 = bottom left corner, and h1 = bottom right corner.

So which squares do the terms that don't fit in this range represent?

*To clarify, I'm trying to figure out how to solve the eight queens problem using the determinant for a linear algebra research project, but I can't figure out how the terms given actually represent the solutions to the problem. Example: $a_{15}n_8e_9k_5f_{10}d_7b_4m_6$, what solution is this supposed to represent and how can I tell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions to Eight Queens Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782685/solutions-to-eight-queens-problem)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't clear enough on the previous post, so I reposted it after making a few clarifications and making the question clearer.

Comment: Is that a problem? I deleted the other post so I'm not spamming or anything.

Comment: Well, you could have edited the question. I believe it's spamming. However, I'm not completely sure if everyone else agrees with me.

Comment: You have misinterpreted the notation rather badly. Letter $a$ with an odd subscript 1 through 15 denotes a cell on the main diagonal, etc.  Of course you failed to properly format these subscripts.

Comment: So then how is it a solution? I understand that the determinant is a 8x15 matrix, and that there are 15 a's originally. But how does these terms represent a solution to the problem...

Comment: How is this not about math? I simply asked how a sequence of 8 terms is supposed to correlate to 8 squares on a chessboard, as it clearly says that these sequences represent solutions.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: Please explain in what sense the question "does not seem to be about math"? Is it because the question is about the *notation* in a mathematical paper rather than the mathematical content? Are questions about notation off-topic here?

Comment: 1. Solving mathematical puzzles, the Eight Queens Problem is a mathematical puzzle I'm working on.
2. Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems, I was struggling with the notation, which could be considered a mathematical concept.
Off topic doesn't seem very valid here.

Comment: @hardmath Why is this question off-topic? The stated reason "does not seem to be about math" makes no sense. Is it because it's a dumb question, because the answer is too obvious? (If that's the reason, a lot more questions here should be closed.) Is it because it's about the notation rather than the mathematical content of the paper in question?

Comment: You guys never even clarified what is off-topic, or what "isn't about math."

Comment: @bof: Given even your minimal editing of the Question, I have voted to reopen.  The faulty premise of the Question, to explain the determinant terms as [algebraic chess notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)), makes it not so much "dumb" or "obvious" as nonsensical.

Comment: @awall4806: It is not "that the determinant is a $8\times 15$ matrix".  There are not fifteen $a$'s but only eight, $a_1,a_3,\ldots,a_{15}$ along the main diagonal, and Glaisher amply illustrates the $8\times 8$ matrix entries used to form the determinant.  The Eight Queens Problem is interesting and has been dealt with in several Questions here, but your misunderstanding will surely clear up once Glaisher's paper is read with greater care.

Comment: The determinant is initially an 8x15 matrix... Maybe you should reread the document and see how he actually got to the 8x8 matrix in the first place.
How is the premise nonsensical? The determinant terms correlate to squares on a chessboard, which form the solutions to the eight queens problem. There is nothing nonsensical about this premise. Rather than actually attempting to help, you just continually say I don't understand anything. You have as of yet not made a single post that has been even remotely helpful.

Comment: Perhaps [this Answer about Glaisher's paper](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/67341/3111) is helpful.  As a topic for a computational linear algebra project, I don't think Glaisher's "determinant" is terribly useful in solving the Eight Queens Problem.  It amounts to a bookkeeping method for distinguishing solutions among all possible row/column permutations.  While permutations give the entire set of terms in the definition of $8\times 8$ determinants (or permanents), one must still check all terms to see if Queens coincide along diagonals (same letter or subscript appearing more than once).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the figure in the article, it appears that the NE-SW diagonals are numbered from $1$ to $15$, while the NW-SE diagonals are labeled with letters $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,k,m,n,p,q,r,s$
starting with the long diagonal and alternating below and above.

Converting from Glaisher's notation to standard chess notation:
$(a_{15},n_8,e_9,k_5,f_{10},d_7,b_4,m_6)=(h1,g7,f5,e8,d2,c4,b6,a3)$
which is a solution of the eight queens problem.

Glaisher's "a" is the a8-h1 diagonal, his "b" is a7-g1, "c" is b8-h2, "d" is a6-f1, "e" ia c8-h3, "f" is a5-e1, etc.; and his "1" ia a8-a8, "2" is a7-b8, "3" is a6-c8, "4" is a5-d8, "5" is a4-e8, "6" is a3-f8, "7" is a2-g8, "8" is a1-h8, "9" is b1-h7, "10" is c1-h6, etc. For example, Glaisher's $f_{10}$ is at the intersection of the a5-e1 and c1-h6 diagonals, i.e., the square d2.

Comment: Ok that's what I was asking! But how did you convert it? I've been trying to figure that out forever but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation to my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!